# Sort list by datatype dropdown list order

Tags: xslt, drop-down-menu, umbraco

How can I sort a list in XSLT in the same order as my datatype drop down list?

I've tried the following without any success:

```
<xsl:variable name="tarrifs" select="umbraco.library:GetPreValues(1601)//preValue" />
<xsl:sort select="tarrifs" order="descending" />
```

I have a list of options in my datatype "Tariff Category" and I want to order the list in my XSLT in the same order as my datatype.

Order of my datatype:

- UE tariff criteria
- UE pricing proposals
- UE tariff schedules
- UE other charges
- UE tariff strategy reports
- MG tariff schedules
- MG tariff reports
- MG ancillary and other charges

Answer (score 0):

To start with, `<xsl:sort...` must appear inside either a `<xsl:apply-templates...` or `<xsl:for-each...` tag.

To sort with subjective logic, like you need, there's a couple of approaches you can take. The simplest is probably this:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>dog</item>
    <item>cat</item>
    <item>horse</item>
    <item>dragonfly</item>
</root>
```

**XSL**

```
<!-- this sheet vars -->
<xsl:variable name='sort_order' select='"dragonfly|horse|dog|cat"' />

<!-- root and static content -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='root/item'>
        <xsl:sort select='string-length(substring-before($sort_order, current()/text()))' data-type='number' />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- iteration content - animal -->
<xsl:template match='item'>
    <p><xsl:value-of select='.' /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

You can test it out at [this XMLPlayground session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/xtX0PB).

The concept, as you can probably see, is to declare the desired sort order as a string, then iteratively sort our nodes based on the position of each node's text value within that sort string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:-

Assuming your xml is this way:-

### XML:

```
<preValues>
    <preValue id="19">Value 1</preValue>
    <preValue id="20">Value 2</preValue>
    <preValue id="21">Value 3</preValue>
</preValues>
```

### XSLT:

If you want to sort by `id` in `descending` order then do this way

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetPreValues(1601)//preValue">
    <xsl:sort select="@id" order="descending" />
    <!-- Do Your Stuff --> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Follow the same methodology to sort by multiple attribute values.